# How to decode mojibake in old Macintosh text files?

Tags: text, character-sets, macintosh

I hope this is an OK place to ask this question.

The Internet Archive has a Macintosh floppy image containing presets for an old E-mu synthesizer module. The page is here [Proteus Preset Libraries](https://archive.org/details/e-mu-proteus-family-preset-libraries)

Using [HFS-utils](https://www.mars.org/home/rob/proj/hfs/) I can list it and extract the files.  The binary files for the synthesizer are OK. It's the text files that look like gibberish.

In LibreOffice it's gibberish:

```
�@�@�@�@�@E-mu PROTEUS Family Factory Presets Library�@

���̃f�B�X�N�ɂ͂��ׂĂ� E-mu PROTEUS �t�@�~���[�̏o�׎��̃v���Z�b�g���[�߂��Ă��܂��B
�t�@�C���`���̓X�^���_�[�h MIDI �t�@�C���E�t�H�[�}�b�g�� Opcode
```

Running a Macintosh emulator, some filenames are gibberish, as is the "text" file.

[image: Root Directory]
[image: Viewing Text File]

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.

My question: what can I do to see the full text of those files?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at them with CiderPress II, I see the same thing you do. The TEXT files have lots of what looks like junk, even as Mac OS Roman.  The one at the top has a single `styl` resource, but the others don't. It's a 1440KB floppy formatted for HFS, and there's nothing wrong with the disk structure, so it's not likely to be general corruption. Maybe a custom character set? Those files don't look like they were meant to be read directly, which makes the TEXT file type an odd choice.

Comment: Maybe old macOS used to put `TEXT` in as fileType under certain conditions for binary files that didn't specify a type? Or maybe a certain compiler did? Yeah definitely some kind of binary file. Googling the recognizable bits of texts gets useful results: `e-mu proteus family factory presets library midi opcode styl` - No idea if this is Mac software but I'd say so as nut much else wrote on HFS disks afaik...

Comment: Are you sure it's not in some Japanese or Chinese encoding?

Comment: @ninjalj: the topmost text file starts `81 40 81 40 81 40 81 40 81 40 45 2d 6d 75 20 50`, which looks like a mix of ASCII and double-byte encoding. I don't know Shift JIS well enough to tell if it's that. The disk label is printed in English.

Comment: @fadden: `iconv -f sjis` converts all those 81 40 to U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE, so Shift-JIS looks like a good guess.

Comment: @ninjalj: I tried iconv with "sjis" and "big5" on one of the files. I get complaints about illegal input sequences, so those don't seem to be correct. Here's one of the filenames: `82 a8 93 c7 82 dd 82 ad 82 be 82 b3 82 a2 81 42`.

Comment: @ninjalj - I tried your `iconv`command and tossed the result to Google Translate, which said it was Japanese, and the English translation looks great!  I have no idea how or why it is in Japanese.   @everyone Thank you so much!  Now to make a bunch of `.docx`files for google translate...

Comment: @fadden: in sjis, that filename converts to "お読みください。", which transliterates as _oyomikudasai_, and means "readme".

Comment: @fadden: according to the wikipedia page on Shift-JIS, there are some deviations between MacJapanese and Shift-JIS, and also some variations of MacJapanese, so maybe you'll need the -c option of iconv to prevent choking on things that are not on Shift-JIS "proper".

Comment: @aMike Probably because there has historically been a big synthesizer gear ecosystem in Japan. For example, Roland corporation (A.K.A. Edirol in some markets before they bought Cakewalk), of MT-32, SC-55, and SC-88 fame, is a Japanese company. If the makers of that product aren't Japanese themselves, you've probably got a disk meant for the Japanese market.

Comment: @ninjalj: the problem seems to be simpler: it doesn't work when I run `iconv` on Ubuntu Linux. Works fine from MINGW on Windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Summarizing the various comments.)

Filenames and text files on HFS disks are usually encoded with an Apple-specific character set, often Mac OS Roman.  This particular disk uses a mix of that and Shift-JIS, which was a common way to encode Japanese text in the 1990s.  There are two steps to decoding a file: (1) extracting it from HFS, (2) converting the Shift-JIS encoding to readable form.  (And possibly (3) translating it to your preferred language.)

You found a solution for step 1.  Step 2 can be accomplished with the [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) utility:

```
iconv -f sjis ç≈èâÇ…Ç®ì«Ç›Ç≠ÇæÇ≥Ç¢ÅB
```

> ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !  ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! 　PROTEUS ファミリーをたくさんお持ちの方へ 　! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !  ! ! ! ! ! ! ! E-mu PROTEUS ファミリーの MIDI エクスクルーシブ・メッセージは特定の機種だけに対応する形式もありますが、プリセットや各種のマップやテーブルなどでは、ほとんど機種が共通で対応できるようになっています。このことにより、多数のライブラリアンのモ各コンピューター/各ソフトウェアで共通に使用できる標準ファイル・フォーマットです。このディスクは Apple 社の Macintosh のフォーマットのディスクに書かれていますが、 [...]

You can send the output to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) to get:

> ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! PROTEUS ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! E-mu PROTEUS family's MIDI キシッシブ・messages are available in a format that is only compatible with specific devices, but in presets, maps, tables, etc., they are compatible with most devices. It is a standard file format that can be used in common with many computers/software. This disk is written in Apple Macintosh format disk.

Translating the filenames is a little harder.  You can convert the characters back to Mac OS Roman encoding, and then feed that into iconv.  "ç≈èâÇ…Ç®ì«Ç›Ç≠ÇæÇ≥Ç¢ÅB" is `82 a8 93 c7 82 dd 82 ad 82 be 82 b3 82 a2 81 42`, which decodes to "お読みください。", which Google Translate interprets as "Please read."

Comment: Seems like Google Translate got problems translating "EXCLUSIVE".